# media.errorCode == -5 media.errorMsg == no valid bitrates

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am working on a Roku Channel. I use SGDEX and when I try to play a HLS stream half of the times it gives the error "[SGDEX] media.errorCode == -5 media.errorMsg == no valid bitrates" and goes back to the main screen. The stream is fine, it plays in iOS apps, android apps, on the browser, on VLC and it also plays on Roku most of the times but some times it gives the error. What is the reason?

Comment: By doing Google search I noticed that this issue is not that unusually...In general looks like a HLS stream issue more than anything else.
This is probably the best link for the info but unfortunately this does not offer You the solution for the problem:
https://emby.media/community/index.php?/topic/80730-media-playback-issues/ 
Also it could happen that VLC and iOS players are able to handle this kind of error better than ROKU hence You don't see the issue when using them. But that's just a wild guess...

Comment: Hello, You handled this issue?. I also get the same issue. I refer to this https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/events/rovideoplayerevent.md. It's a one-time Video player refresh required so I refresh video player when I getting this error. For any other solution please discuss.